# Why does the border for <body> not surround the whole body?

Tags: html, border

I'm trying to get a border to surround the entire body of my page, but when I add the border property it only goes about halfway down the page, stopping about 20px under the content. The messenger isn't allowing me to post the html without adding extensive comments. This is the CSS. Thank you.

```
body {
    border: green dotted 2px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px outset green;
    border-radius: 25px 10px 25px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

p  {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: 
}

img {
    width: 95px;
}

#treelink {
    width: 120px;
    border: outset green 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px green;
}
```

Comment: Please try and post your HTML - very hard to help without an example. Your `body` CSS looks fine to me so without seeing the rest of the markup it's impossible to know what the issue is. The body will wrap to the height of the content inside it, so if that is only so high you can use `height: 100%` as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it out on jsfiddle, and I believe that you have to add this.

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

I'm guessing it's because the body is dynamically sized depending on what's inside it, unless you specify in the css. Same with the html; you need to specify the hmtl as width: 100% and height: 100% so the html itself is as large as the entire page.

Comment: i always find 100% width and height leads to scroll bars up / down / left / right so i tend to reduce the %.